Product of elementary matrices in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ equal to the identity matrix.
For $i\neq j$ define the matrix $E_{i,j}$ in  $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ to be the matrix that difers from the identity by a $1$ in the position $(i,j)$. I want to check if there exists matrices $E_{i_1,j_1},\dots,E_{i_l,j_l}$ such that $E_{i_1,j_1}\cdots E_{i_l,j_l}=I_n$. I was able to do it for $l=2$:
$E_{i,j}=I_n+A_{i,j}$, where $A_{i,j}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in $(i,j)$ and zeroes elsewhere. Hence:
$$(I_n+A_{i_1,j_1})(I_n+A_{i_2,j_2})=I_n\Rightarrow A_{i_1,j_1}+A_{i_2,j_2}+A_{i_1,j_1}A_{i_2,j_2}=0$$
Now, using that $A_{i,j}A_{k,l}=0$ if $k\neq j$ and $A_{i,j}A_{j,l}=A_{i,l}$ we get that:

If $j_1=i_2$ then the equation becomes $A_{i_1,j_1}+A_{i_2,j_2}+A_{i_1,j_2}=0$ which is not possible in  $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$.
If $j_1\neq i_2$ then the equation becomes $A_{i_1,j_1}+A_{i_2,j_2}=0$ which implies $(i_1,j_1)=(i_2,j_2)$.

Hence, $E_{i_1,j_1}E_{i_2,j_2}=I_n$ iff $(i_1,j_1)=(i_2,j_2)$. My guess is that $E_{i_1,j_1}\cdots E_{i_l,j_l}=I_n$ iff $E_{i_1,j_1}\cdots E_{i_l,j_l}$ can be written as a product of squares, but I'm not sure how to aproach the general case.
Thanks for your help.

I take it that what you mean by "written as a product of squares" is that the first pair of $E_{i,j}$ are equal and so on? After all $E_{1,3}=(E_{1,2}E_{2,3})^2$ is a square.

It is clear that for $l$ even there are always solutions, just by grouping in pairs. Assume $(i_{2k},j_{2k})=(i_{2k+1},j_{2k+1})$, then we have
$$E_{i_1,j_1}E_{i_2,j_2}\cdots E_{i_l,j_l} = E_{i_1,j_1}^2\cdots E_{i_{l-1},j_{l-1}}^2 = I\cdots I = I.$$
I assume this is what you refer to in your last sentence. Are you only looking for the existence of solutions, or do you want to know them all?
For $l=3$, your methods above extend to show that there are no solutions, though it gets a little messy. Since this is also trivially true for $l=1$, it seems fair to conjecture that there are no solutions for $l$ odd, though I don't have a proof.
Here is the proof for $l=3$. I will write $A_{a,b}$ in your notation as $(a,b)$ for my convenience. Addition and multiplication of such tuples are still the operations of associated matrices.
We consider ([Eq. $1$])
$$E_{a,b}E_{c,d}E_{f,g} = I+(a,b)+(c,d)+(f,g)+(a,b)(c,d)+(a,b)(f,g)+(c,d)(f,g)+(a,b)(c,d)(f,g).$$
We seek to find $a,b,c,d,f,g$ such that ([Eq. $2$])
$$(a,b)+(c,d)+(f,g)+(a,b)(c,d)+(a,b)(f,g)+(c,d)(f,g)+(a,b)(c,d)(f,g) = 0.$$
As the first three terms are non-zero, we need to cancel these, which can only be done by identifying each of these terms with another term in the sum. Note that the first three terms cannot cancel amongst themselves, i.e. we cannot have $(a,b)=(c,d)$, $(c,d)=(f,g)$ or $(a,b)=(f,g)$. The two first would imply that Eq. $1$ is equal to $E_{f,g}$ or $E_{a,b}$ respectively, which are clearly not $I$. The final case cannot satisfy Eq. $1$ being $I$ either, since that would imply
$$E_{a,b}E_{c,d}E_{a,b} = I \:\Leftrightarrow\: E_{a,b}(E_{a,b}E_{c,d}E_{a,b})E_{a,b} = E_{a,b}E_{a,b} \:\Leftrightarrow\: E_{c,d} = I,$$
and this is clearly not the case.
Thus, the first three terms must cancel with some collection of the four following terms. Exactly three of these terms must be non-zero, since if all four were non-zero, we have an odd number of terms, which clearly cannot give $0$.
Thus, either the degree $3$ term $(a,b)(c,d)(f,g)$ is zero, and all the degree $2$ terms are non-zero, or exactly one of the degree $2$ terms is zero, with the degree $3$ term surviving.
In the first case, all degree $2$ terms must be non-zero. By the multiplication formula you provide, we see that this means $b=c$, $b=f$ and $d=f$. But the degree $3$ term is non-zero exactly if $b=c$ and $d=f$, so all terms would be non-zero, and we would not have a solution.
Now, assume the degree $3$ term is non-zero, i.e. $b=c$ and $d=f$, which means we must assume $b\neq f$ such that exactly one of the degree $2$ terms becomes $0$. Eq. $2$ becomes
$$(a,b)+(c,d)+(f,g)+(a,d)+(c,g)+(a,g) = 0.$$
Now you can just go through the cases, since $(a,b)$ must be identical to one of the three latter terms. For example, if $(a,b)=(a,d)$, then $b=d$, but we already assumed $b=c$, and then $E_{c,d}=E_{b,b}$ is not well defined. All other cases run into similar contradictions at the first or second identification, and so there are no solutions.
I imagine a general solution could use Jordan normal forms or something similar, but I didn't manage to work it out.

Thanks. What I would like to do if possible (though it may be really dificult) is to show that the only solutions are the ones that can be written as sums of squares (which of course implies that $l$ must be even). However, being able to show that there are no solutions for $n$ odd would be a big step in the proof.
